# Printing continuously regenerating barcode images via a thermal printer using Java

Tags: java

I have a java code which generates barcode image with the name barcode.jpg in the same folder as the residing jar file.  I do this

```
Image bcode = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getImage("barcode.jpg");
if (bcode != null) {
    oTokenPrinter.setTokenParameters(strTokenNumber, bcode);
}
PrintRequestAttributeSet aset = new HashPrintRequestAttributeSet();
aset.add(OrientationRequested.PORTRAIT);
aset.add(new MediaPrintableArea((float) 16.0, (float) 20.5, (float) 184.0, (float) 228.5, 1000));
System.out.println(aset);
PrinterJob oJob = PrinterJob.getPrinterJob();
PageFormat pf = oJob.defaultPage();
oJob.setPrintable(oTokenPrinter, pf);
System.out.println(aset);
System.out.println("Printing Started...\n");


try {
    oJob.print(aset);
} catch (PrinterException ex) {
    Logger.getLogger(EntryHandler.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
}
```

`setTokenParameters` function is

```
public void setTokenParameters(String strTokenId, Image barcode) {
    strTokenID = strTokenId;
    BarcodeImage = barcode;
}
```

and this resides in the same class which contains the print() method.

```
public int print(Graphics g, PageFormat pf, int iPage) throws
        PrinterException {
    if (iPage > 0) {
        return NO_SUCH_PAGE;
    }

    /* User (0,0) is typically outside the imageable area, so we must
     * translate by the X and Y values in the PageFormat to avoid clipping
     */
    Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;

    g2d.translate(pf.getImageableX(), pf.getImageableY());


    /* Now we perform our rendering */


    g.setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.BOLD, 10));

    /*Printing Begins*/

    if (BarcodeImage != null) {
        System.out.println("Started Printing...\n");

        g.drawImage(BarcodeImage, 16, -10, 130, 60, null);
        g.drawString("Token ID: " + strTokenID, 18, 60);
        g.dispose();
        System.out.println("Finished Printing");

    } else {

        System.out.print("Image not loaded");

    }
    /*Finished Printing.*/

    /* tell the caller that this page is part of the printed document */
    return PAGE_EXISTS;
}
```

This is what I do. The generation of image is in a thread and it keeps on overwriting and I can see that when I open the image. But the problem is that, while printing it keeps on printing the same image. Only the image is the same everytime, the token ID keeps on varying.

Any solution for this. I have tried deleting the image everytime after printing. But that doesnt work. I have also tried to clear printer spooler by running a .bat file through my java program. No avail.

**NOTE: This happens only when the printer is a thermal printer. I tried on a normal HP LaserJet and it works fine. But there the problem is I have to waste A4 sheets. I need this thing in receipt size on a thermal printer.**

Comment: did you try to simplify the task? for example to print "hello, world" on the same printer. Is it a problem of printer buffer size?

Comment: As I said, I am able to print whatever strings even if they are varying....ONLY THE IMAGE KEEPS ON REPEATING[its always the first image]...and also note that this thing works on HP laserjet...ONLY ON THERMAL PRINTER is this not working....

Comment: also note, the image is regenerating properly...as if i open barcode.jpg and preview its the new one....only it keeps printing the first one....dont know where the printer[or whatever] keeps the first one with it...

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like the printer is caching the image. Try appending a random number to the image name each time perhaps?

Edit:

Another possibility is that in the line:

```
Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getImage("barcode.jpg");
```

The toolkit is caching the image rather than reloading it.

Edit 2:

From the javadoc for getImage:

> Returns an image which gets pixel data
>   from the specified file, whose format
>   can be either GIF, JPEG or PNG. The
>   underlying toolkit attempts to resolve
>   multiple requests with the same
>   filename to the same returned Image.
>   Since the mechanism required to
>   facilitate this sharing of Image
>   objects may continue to hold onto
>   images that are no longer of use for
>   an indefinite period of time,
>   developers are encouraged to implement
>   their own caching of images by using
>   the createImage variant wherever
>   available.

To me that sounds like its caching the image - have you tried using createImage() instead?

Comment: Yeah i tried the same...i kept changing the name of the image with current time.AS in the current time would be the neame of the image. Also I deleted the same after printing. So everytime a new image is generated with current time as its name and deleted after printing. But no avail.

Comment: as i said, i also ran a bat file through the program to clear and restart the spooler. But no change again.

Comment: Ive edited - is the toolkit caching the image? (though if it were you'd see the problem on all printers...)

Comment: but it should not if the name of the image is changed every time. right? and there is also your comments inside the braces.

Comment: Hmm...one thing id do - its more of a design thing rather than a bug fix, but it may help - is to call your files barcode_<token id>.jpg. That way you only need to keep track of one number, and your image names are instrinsically linked to the token to which they apply. Your print method can just take an id, generate the filename from this and load it - this should ensure that you always match id and barcode.

Comment: yes...i did as is said...token id is nothing but a string with the current date + time. I gave the same name for the image as well. Thats it keeps changing every time it is generated. But that too failed.

Comment: to update: with createimage() ...it is not printing the image at all.